# How can I add as many sessions as I want?

Tags: mobaxterm

In Mobaxterm, is there a way to add as many remote sessions as want?

I don't see any options in the file `mobaxterm.ini`

Answer (score 4):

To do this, edit the file `mobaxterm.ini` and add the line

`SettingsSave = 0`

Under the [Misc] section

Note: Close any mobaxterm sessions you may have open before doing the edit

Comment: A bit more info on what this change does would help

Comment: @DaveM, add this property at the end of `[misc]` section in the ini file and open new mobaxterm console to check it.

Comment: @Ikaros,  I updated the question would you please tell me what to do now??

Comment: @S.K Venkar, any input you have?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button.  Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @indarjeet Gour, Plz specify your question as new one. I couldn't see any question update here.

Comment: it did not work for me.

Comment: It doesn't works for me. The session does not gets save in the user session on the left pane. What is that am I missing